# What is the most optimal way of using sequence Generator in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, snowflake-schema

I am using below SQL on snowflake database for creating random Sequence based on Date, but it takes almost 4 hours in 2XL warehouse and majority time is spent on window function,

```
SELECT 
   DAY_DT,
   AGMT_ID, 
   COUNTRY_CD,
   CUSTOMER_ID,
   SUM(AMOUNT_YTD),
   SUM(AMOUNT_MTD)
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY 1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Contract_Id 
from DB_1.SCHEMA01.TABLE_Test 
where DAY_DT = Current_DATE()-1 
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

(163Million rows are there in table_test)
Is there any alternate method to write above window function efficiently so that runtime is optimized?

Comment: Why if you are doing a group by on a whole lot of fields to to want an unstable set of numbers across those agregates? the contract_id, will be random from query to query?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sequence with no gaps you will need [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)

but then you should use:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null) AS Contract_Id
```

but that has to all be done on one node. If you just need numbers that go up.

use [SEQ8](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html)()

```
SEQ8() as Contract_Id
```

So using this CTE with some fake data to test those out:

```
WITH TABLE_Test as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES
    (Current_DATE()-1, 10,100,1000, 1.23, 43.21),
    (Current_DATE()-1, 11,100,1000, 1.23, 43.21),
    (Current_DATE()-1, 10,100,1000, 1, 1),
    (Current_DATE()-1, 11,100,1000, 1, 1),
    (Current_DATE()-1, 12,100,1000, 1, 1)
    v(DAY_DT, AGMT_ID, COUNTRY_CD, CUSTOMER_ID, AMOUNT_YTD, AMOUNT_MTD)
)
```

you SQL gives:

| DAY_DT | AGMT_ID | COUNTRY_CD | CUSTOMER_ID | SUM(AMOUNT_YTD) | SUM(AMOUNT_MTD) | CONTRACT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-15 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 2.23 | 44.21 | 1 |
| 2022-03-15 | 11 | 100 | 1000 | 2.23 | 44.21 | 2 |
| 2022-03-15 | 12 | 100 | 1000 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

thus the SEQ option works a charm:

```
SELECT 
   DAY_DT,
   AGMT_ID, 
   COUNTRY_CD,
   CUSTOMER_ID,
   SUM(AMOUNT_YTD),
   SUM(AMOUNT_MTD),
   SEQ8() + 1 AS Contract_Id 
from TABLE_Test 
where DAY_DT = Current_DATE()-1 
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

as does the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY null) version.

```
SELECT 
   DAY_DT,
   AGMT_ID, 
   COUNTRY_CD,
   CUSTOMER_ID,
   SUM(AMOUNT_YTD),
   SUM(AMOUNT_MTD),
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null) AS Contract_Id 
UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Contract_Id 
from TABLE_Test 
where DAY_DT = Current_DATE()-1 
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

The SEQn() version will be much faster, but can have gaps in the numbers.

Given there is no ORDER BY sorting in the data, both methods (row number, seq) each query could/will have different allocation of values.

Comment: Thank you Simeon, that answers my question :)